# Find formulas $X, Y$

Tags: logic

> Find formulas $X, Y$ such that $((\forall b X) \implies (\forall b Y)) \not \equiv (\forall b (X \implies Y))$. Justify your answer with reference to relevant interpretations.

This is logic, not mathematics. In this sense I am confused how to find the formulas.

Comment: Who says logic isn't mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have three sentences of interest:  $\forall b X, \forall b Y,$ and $\forall b (X \implies Y)$.  You need the two sides of the $\not \equiv$ sign to disagree, so find truth values of those sentences that make it so.  Presumably $X$ is really a predicate and the sentence is $X(b)$ so you might have some $b$s for which $X(b)$ is true and some for which it is false.  On the right you have to select the same $b$ for the argument of both $X$ and $Y$

Added:  There are four combinations of true and false for $X$ and $Y$.  Say we have an element in our domain for each one.  Then $\forall b X$ and $\forall bY$ are both false, so the left side is true.  $\forall b (X \implies Y)$ is false because of the element for which $X$ is true and $Y$ is false.

Comment: Do I define a domain?

Comment: No, you just need to think about which value pairs $(X(b),Y(b))$ should be represented.  It doesn't matter how many elements you have, so you might as well have no more than four.  If $X$ and $Y$ are always true, both sides of the $\not \equiv$ are true and it doesn't work.  If they are both always false again both sides are true and it doesn't work, so you need some others represented.

Comment: If there is any $b$ such that $X(b)$ is false, the left side is true.  It seems we should try to make the right side false.  What does that take?

Comment: Does that mean no $b$? Ie, we have a predicate $X$ such that $D = \{1, 2\}$, the domain. Then $X = P(b)$ where $X = \{1 \}$?`